# How to create for loops in bash script?

Tags: bash

Usually when writing for loops in bash script, I will write like this:

```
FILE[1]=/tempA/aaa

FILE[2]=tempB/bbb

for FILES in `ls -1 ${FILE[@]}`
do 
   echo $FILES
done
```

this will display the FILE depending how many I initialize the FILE because it is in array.
I need to create a bash script to copy files from a directory to another directory.

assuming like this:

```
SOURCE[1]=/tempA/source/aaa

SOURCE[2]=/tempB/source/bbb


DEST[1]=/tempA/dest/

DEST[2]=/tempB/dest/
```

I need to copy from source[1] to dest[1] also from source[2] to dest[2]. So my question how I need to write the FOR loops? or maybe there are another way to do other than for loops?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate over the array:

```
$ SOURCE=( /tempA/source/aaa /tempB/source/bbb )      # declare SOURCE array
$ DEST=( /tempA/dest /tempB/dest )                    # declare DEST array
$ for i in ${!SOURCE[@]}; do echo "${SOURCE[$i]}" "${DEST[$i]}"; done
/tempA/source/aaa /tempA/dest
/tempB/source/bbb /tempB/dest
```

Depending upon the operation that needs to be performed, replace `echo` with the appropriate command.  (You might declare arrays in the form mentioned above, thereby obviating the need to declare array elements one-by-one.)

Comment: thanks a lot for your time to reply. my script already working now by using my own code. In future maybe i can use your way. Thanks again!